# ValidatorEnable is not defined when rolled with AJAX

Tags: c#, validation, ajax.net

I have some webforms which have been working fine with various static and dynamically generated validators.

For some reason now that I have implemented UpdatePanels on the forms, when I manually call the ValidatorEnable() method on one of them (when I click a checkbox) I get the "ValidatorEnable is not defined" error message.

I am passing the same clientID etc into the method that I was using before I implemented the AJAX.net controls

It would seem .net isnt rendering the /WebResource.axd?d=aUu4P3dfjWWyw3KQ9t2ZdqxnzYhrtq9uWWiRZduXE-g1 script to the page, adding it manually I get other missing JS objects. So how can I force it to register the relevant scripts?

N.B. The validators in question are being rendered in a repeater

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if I put a disabled validator on the page outside the repeater it correctly adds the relevant scripts.

This is hacky but does actually work

N.B.This only got rid of the Javascript error, the validators don't appear to be registering on the page, so IsValid is always true no matter what.